# How to create Stack using a LinkedList

Tags: java

I must create Stack by using Linked List. Here is my LinkedList class:

```
package stack;

import java.util.EmptyStackException;

public class List {

    Element head;
    int size = 0;

    public void Add(Object value) {
        if (size == 0) {
            head = new Element(value);
            size++;
            return;
        }

        Insert(size, value);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, Object value) {
        if (index > size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Bad index");
        }

        Element tmp = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index -1 ; i++) {
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }

        Element newElement = new Element(value);
        newElement.next = tmp.next;
        tmp.next = newElement;
        size++;
    }

    public int Size() {
        return size;
    }

    public Object Get(int index) {
        if (index > size - 1) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index doesn't exist");
        }
        Element tmp = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            tmp = tmp.next;

        }
        System.out.println(tmp.value.toString());
        return tmp;
    }

    public Object Set(int index, Object value) {
        if (index > size - 1) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index doesn't exist");
        }

        Element tmp = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }

        Element returnValue = new Element(value);
        returnValue = tmp;
        tmp.value = value;

        return returnValue;
    }

    public Object Delete(int index) {

        Element tmp;
        tmp = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++) {
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }

        Element returnValue;
        returnValue = tmp;
        head = tmp.next;
        size--;
        return returnValue;

    }

    public boolean Contains(Object value) {
        Element tmp = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            tmp = tmp.next;
            if (tmp.value == value) {
                System.out.println("true");
                return true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("False");
        return false;
    }

    public boolean IsEmpty() {
        return Size() > 0;
    }

    public void Clear() {

        size = 0;
    }

    public void Display() throws EmptyStackException {
        if (size <= 0) {
            throw new EmptyStackException();

        }
        Element tmp = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.println(tmp.value.toString());
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
    }
}
```

and i got Stack interface

```
public interface IStack {

    public interface Stack {

        public void push(Object value); // odłóż na stos

        public Object pop() throws EmptyStackException; //pobierz ze stosu

        public Object peek() throws EmptyStackException; //odczytaj ze stosu,
        // and some others
```

Any1 have am idea how to create pop method?

Comment: You should try to take a look at JDK `Stack` class. Most likely you'll find an answer there.

Comment: Consider too what happens for `Insert(0, ...)`. After correcting that, consider what is easier: inserting & removing in front or at the end of the list?

Comment: I had the opposite of this as an interview question once, good stuff.  This is really just an exercise in implementing your LinkedList and wrapping it inside of a Stack class.  Stack operations are really well know; push and pop...that's pretty much it.

Comment: Is this a homework question by any chance?

Comment: I assume this is homework so I will give you a hint instead of a solution.  If you understand what it means to pop an item from a stack, then there are two methods you have already defined in your `List` class that combined will get you what you need for `pop`.  You need to figure out which ones.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList is already a stack, it has pop, push and peek methods. Just create an adapter class and use those methods